# C#: Process working in user session

Tags: c#, service

I need to create an application which should run in the same session with user. And it actually starts up at login.

The application itself - it's a client which is running in background and periodically requests data from server, and shows popup windows with received data. This app can be stopped and restarted.

As I understand I can't organize this app as windows service because it can't be launched for several users. What is the solution?

Comment: just write a normal WPF/WinForms/whatever Application and have the user install it to his startup-folder (or make the registry-entries in your setup, ...)

Comment: The question is not "how to launch in user session", but "how to let start/stop application in one simple action?". If this is a service then I can do "start MyService/stop MyService" even remotely.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (for all users on the machine) or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (for a specific user), then the program gets started on logon.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: Can it be applied to a windows service application?

Comment: Its for launching a program in the users session on logon. As you stated your problem, you want a process in the users session, not a service. And this method starts the program when the user logs on.